# How to use enviroment variable in java command line argument

Tags: java, linux, docker

I have linux and enviroment variable `$PASS`, eg `123`.

I want to run java application and pass this variable.
Example:

```
java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/certs -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$PASS my.jar
```

And  suspect that `$PASS` will be replaced to its value during start process. But in running application I see strinng `$PASS` instead of `123`

My question is, how to properly run java app with command line with enviroment variable

upd:
It's work from bash, but didn't work in docker with command in dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /my.jar
```

whre `JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/certs -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$PASS`

Comment: Replacing `$PASS` with the value of the environment variable is what a shell does (usually bash or one of its relatives on Linux). If you don't hand that line to a shell to execute it, but execute it some other way, then nothing will replace that string. How/where to you run that command? Is that in a terminal? Or some input-field in another application?

Comment: It's work from bash, but didn't work in docker with command
`ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /my.jar`
whre `JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/certs -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$PASS`

Comment: Where do you expect docker to take the environment variables from? Environment variables in Docker are either set in the docker file or **explicitly** given when using `docker run`, it won't automagically pick up the environment variables from the shell (that would defeat the purpose of having a contianer that's separate from the outside).